# SSH via script is not working

Tags: unix, ssh

I want to SSH to a machine (call it A). It's sshd config file looks like below:

```
AllowGroups wheel
AllowTcpForwarding no
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
Banner /etc/issue
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
Ciphers aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr
Compression delayed
GatewayPorts no
MACs hmac-sha1
MaxSessions 1
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin yes
PermitTunnel no
PermitUserEnvironment no
Protocol 2
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
StrictModes yes
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib64/ssh/sftp-server
UsePAM yes
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
X11Forwarding no
```

I have another machine (call it B - ssh client)
Now, if I try to ssh to machineA as below, it works perfect:

```
ssh root@machineA
```

and then interactively provide password. Works perfect!

Now, I try passing password via a script using `sshpass` utility as below:

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh -vvv -o=StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@machineA
```

This fails.

Last few lines from debug of `-vvv` gives below:

```
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 51 padlen 13 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

`/var/log/auth.log` on machine A says below:

```
Connection from machineB port 44408
Failed password for root from machineB port 44408 ssh2
Connection closed by machineB port 44408 [preauth]
```

`lastb` command gives below:

```
root     ssh:notty    machineB    Sun Jul  3 04:20 - 04:20  (00:00)
root     ssh:notty    machineB    Sun Jul  3 04:19 - 04:19  (00:00)
```

I have been reading around for it. But, not something that I can stop at. Do you have any pointers? What could be the problem?

Anything related to `sshpass` or something?

Comment: I don't know what your problem is, but my advice would be that allowing login as "root" over a network with password authentication is INSECURE.  At least use pubkey authentication.

Comment: Yea, I agree to that. But, I am debugging a web app that does this over TLS and in LAN environment and not on internet or cloud machine such as AWS.

Comment: So ... you can guarantee that you will never have a hacker, or a disgruntled employee on your LAN?

Comment: :) Let us not get into that at the moment. Let us leave that discussion for some other day.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to narrow the problem:

- Try with a simpler password, without special characters.
- Try with a user different than root.
- Try using certificates instead of password. 
  That is explained here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key , https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2 etc.

Have a look at the server logs as well, check /var/log/secure or alike.

Comment: I can do this using certificate. But, my app provides dual functionality - password based auth and cert based auth. No issues with cert based but I need to make password based work as well.

Comment: Did you try those tips above? Did you find the secure log in your machine?